# App crashes when LinearProgressIndicator is placed inside a Row

Tags: android, windows, flutter, dart

I have the following code in my Flutter project:

```
           Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                 Text("data"),
                 LinearProgressIndicator(),
                ],
              )
```

That alone is enough to cause an error:

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#d2962 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
package:flutter/…/rendering/box.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 1978 pos 12: 'hasSize'
```

Any idea?

Comment: Try giving a Specific width to the LinearProgressIndicator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SizedBox(
        width: 100.0,
        child: LinearProgressIndicator(),
        );
```

// The issue is with the size

Answer (score 0):

Just expand your `LinearProgressIndicator` inside the `Row`.

```
  Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Text("data"),
      Expanded(child: LinearProgressIndicator()),
    ],
  ),
```